# How can I avoid crawling URLs that "do" things like unsubscribing a person from a mailing list

Tags: web-crawler

I am writing a tool that crawls urls in emails so a user can do focused searches. is there a way to tell a visited URL that we are a crawler so that the user does not get subscribed or unsubscribed from a mailing list or so that other actions in the URL are not likely to be taken.

Otherwise, is there any smart way to generally discover that a URL is meant to only be visited by a human that wishes to take some action?

Comment: Frankly, when you're dealing with e-mail links, they're so targeted that getting your customer subscribed/unsubscribed to something is probably the least of your worries. Imagine if they receive spam and you crawl the links before the user has marked the e-mail as spam: simply visiting a link from a junk message may signal the spammer that the e-mail address is valid and the user can get subscribed for **even more spam!** Tricky situation, it seems that you really have to study the e-mail content and make sure that you don't visit the wrong links.

Answer (score 1):

One way that would help anyway, would be to obey any robots.txt file that is available in the root of the site.

The site author should have this setup so that any crawler stays away from areas they don't want them to go into.

Stewart.

Answer (score 0):

In general, no.

There's no way to reliably infer whether a given URL "does" anything in particular (I guess you could look for patterns e.g. "unsubscribe", but that would hardly be reliable).

And there's no magic "I'm a robot" flag that you can set when making the HTTP requests.